# unable to import a module from different folder -python

Tags: python

This is the structure of my code:

```
---root-dir/
        ----app/
            -----config/
                    ------ __init__.py
                    ------   config.py
            -----constants/
                    ------ __init__.py
                    ------ ****.py
                    ------ ****.py
            -----exception/
                    ------ __init__.py
            -----main/
                    ------ __init__.py
                    ------ controller.py
            -----util/
                    ------ __init__.py
                    ------ picklehelp.py
```

Now when I do the below import in `/main/controller.py` and run, it does not work.

```
from app.util.picklehelp import func
```

How can I import the modules, without doing maximum changes in code so that it can work in any machine irrespective of the path location and OS

Comment: does your `app` directory has a `__init__.py` ?

Comment: yes. `app` directory has a `__init__.py `

Comment: Do you get any errors? If yes please post your stack trace

Comment: Are these all `__init__.py` files empty?

Comment: yes. the `__init__.py` files are empty. 

below is the stack trace.
`python controller.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 10, in <module>
    from app.util.picklehelp import picklehelp
ImportError: No module named app.util.picklehelp`

Comment: yeah , they coded traceback for a reason , so show it.

Comment: You can import `app` from `root-dir`. The module `main` cant import because `app.utils` is not in its path.

Comment: @SachinKukreja  you mean `from root-dir.app.util.picklehelp import func` ??

Comment: Make a program in root-dir which is the main python program which calls the main/controller.py

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be adding to the `sys.path` the path to your app (without the filename):

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"root-dir\app\util")

from picklehelp import func
```

> How can I import the modules, without doing maximum changes in code so that it can work in any machine* irrespective of the path location and OS

The `sys` module works at any operating system that Python supports. Then, there can be other modules indepent to an OS, like `winsound`, `winreg` or `windows` in the Windows operating system.

<sub>***** Not any machine can run Python</sub>

Comment: in this case we need to have the absolute path in `os.path.append(r"root-dir\app\util")`, which can vary with other users. I am looking for a solution where any user can pick my code and run, without doing any path change

Comment: Oops, I've put `os`, the actual module seems to be `sys`. `os.path` is a module for manipulation of paths, like `pathlib`.

Comment: i thinks that's `sys.path.append`

Comment: Yes, it is the `sys` module.

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory to root-dir. Run `python -m app.main.controller`

This will run your app as a module.

Comment: This does works, but i see there is a huge difference in the response time. when I run it from pycharm with a simulation of 50 threads it takes on an avg 80-90 ms, but while running as `python -m app.main.controller` takes around 800-900 ms. i don't understand why the performance degrades.

Comment: Each '.' brings a lag.

Comment: Restructuring the code might help. You can't avoid the importing time costs if you can't restructure the code.

Comment: well i moved the main dir above app dir :). no changes in code

Comment: Good for you...!